# Laravel PHP Version

Tags: laravel, composer-php, version

when I check my PHP version it shows 8.0.3 but I changed the version to 7.2.0 in Laragon.
when I run the composer update command in Laravel it generates the error

Problem 1

- Root composer.json requires PHP ^7.2.0 but your PHP version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.

Problem 2

- laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.8.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in PHP because your PHP version does not match Laravel or the packages you use. Now it's better to go to the composer.json file that says the last version you can have this way.

```
"require": {
    "php": "^ 8.0.2",
```

For example, in Laravel version 9, the minimum PHP version is 8.0.2

Comment: `"require": {"php": "^8.0.2",`
Still the same issue
Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.8.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].

Comment: Iam working on laragon when i installed 7.4 version but it still picking 8.0.3 version

Answer (score 0):

In your command line type:

```
composer require
```

press enter and then it will ask for the package

```
search for a package : php
```

press enter and then it will ask for the version

```
Enter the version constraint to require (or leave blank to use the latest version) : 7.1.3
```

press enter twice. Hope this helps.